# If I escape and give my die to an adventurer, can he use the rolled value immediately?

Tags: escape-the-curse-of-the-temple

Rules say, for a player who escape,

> ...he can give one of his dice to any adventurer still inside the temple. This adventurer may use the die immediately.

Does this mean the person can use the face value of the die and use it for that current turn, then continue to use that die to roll future turns?

Edit: the best link to the rules I could find [here](http://www.jumbo.eu/media/products/assets/manuals/d1a46a58-fc62-54ed-a492-4505f595ef71.pdf).

Comment: I'm going to have to check my physical copy of the rules, because I've always played it as "it's a new die, it needs to be rolled before it can be used" but then I'm not sure where I picked that up from.

Comment: I will update the question with a link to the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit old but I think I have an answer to it (sort of).  The rules state:

```
After a player has performed one action, he must re-roll all dice used for this action.
```

There's room for interpretation but I'd say that you could pass a die you didn't use for the escape action and they could use the face value.  However, the rules pretty much state that you can't pass a key you used to escape to someone such that they can use it as a key to escape.  As per the wording in the rulebook under the escape action:

```
 Each player must roll the required number of key icons by himself!
```

The wording that 'This adventurer may use the die immediately' also seems to suggest the face value passed can be used for an action but I wonder if that is a case of slightly imprecise wording.

I strongly suspect the intent of the rules is that the passed die must be rolled before its face value can be used but they don't explicitly state that or the opposite, except for the case of keys in an escape action, which seems fairly clear to me.  Whenever I've played the game it has always been considered a new die that you must roll in order to use it and that is the simplest interpretation of the rules, in my opinion, and how I am likely to always play it.

I think the issue is a minor one that is best to house rule as you see fit but I definitely wouldn't allow people to pass keys they rolled for an escape action for others to use as a key, that definitely seems wrong to me and would reduce the tension at the end of the game too much.